# How to deal with Forms that are related to more than one entity(Service)?

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

In my application I use a unit of work and repository pattern.
I have created services to manage crud operations like this

```
public DepartmentService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper):base(unitOfWork, mapper)
{
}
public async Task<IEnumerable<DepartmentDto>> GetAllDepartmentsAsync()
{
    var department = await unitOfWork.Departments.GetAllAsync();
    return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DepartmentDto>>(department);
}
public async Task<bool> InsertDepartmentAsync(DepartmentDto departmentDto)
{
    var department = mapper.Map<Department>(departmentDto);
    return await unitOfWork.Departments.AddAsync(department);
}
public async Task<bool> UpdateDepartmentAsync(DepartmentDto departmentDto,int id)
{
}
public async Task<bool> RemoveDepartmentAsync(DepartmentDto departmentDto,int id)
{
}
public async Task<int> CompleteAsync()
{
    return await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
}
```

And in **Department Form** I use it like this

```
private readonly DepartmentService departmentService;
public Frm_Department(DepartmentService departmentService)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.departmentService= departmentService;
}
```

Now I have an Employee Form that contains text boxes and combo box for the Department.
My question is in this situation do I inject services in Employee Form (Employee Service, Department Service) or is there another way to do it? and how about when there are more than two services ?

```
public EmployeeService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper):base(unitOfWork, mapper)
{
}
public async Task<IEnumerable<EmployeeDto>> GetAllEmployeesDetailsAsync()
{
    var employee = await unitOfWork.Employees.GetAllIncluding(
                    emp => emp.FkCountryNavigation,
                    emp => emp.FkDepartmentNavigation,
                    emp => emp.FkGenderNavigation,
                    emp => emp.FkJobTitleNavigation,
                    emp => emp.FkMaritalStatusNavigation,
                    emp => emp.FkProvincesNavigation,
                    emp => emp.FkTownNavigation);
    return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<EmployeeDto>>(employee);
}
public async Task<bool> InsertEmployeeAsync(EmployeeDto employeeDto)
{
    var employee = mapper.Map<Employee>(employeeDto);
    return await unitOfWork.Employees.AddAsync(employee);
}
    public async Task<int> CompleteAsync()
{
    return await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
}
```

This is EmployeeDto

```
public partial class EmployeeDto
{
 public string IdEmployee { get; set; }
 public string FirstNameEmployee { get; set; }
 public string LastNameEmployee { get; set; }

 public virtual DepartmentDto FkDepartmentNavigationDto { get; set; }
 public virtual GenderDto FkGenderNavigationDto { get; set; }
 public virtual JobTitleDto FkJobTitleNavigationDto { get; set; }
 public virtual MaritalStatusDto FkMaritalStatusNavigationDto { get; set; }
 public virtual CountryDto FkCountryNavigationDto { get; set; }
 public virtual ProvinceDto FkProvincesNavigationDto { get; set; }
 public virtual TownDto FkTownNavigationDto { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to separate your logic from the forms somehow, you can think of all of your forms as just views and nothing more. Make it so that the forms expose only their controls (textboxes, labels, buttons .. everything) as plain properties. Make a new folder containing classes for the logic of each of your forms.
Each class will have a constructor that accepts a form and the services that will be used by it. All you are left to do is to populate those classes with event handler methods for the events of the exposed control properties, subscribe to those events in the constructor

> (for example->  _form.EnterButton.Click += YourEventHandler .. repeat
> that for each exposed control)

and finally use the services inside those event handler methods to write your logic. After inserting the needed logic/changes inside the form you can simply make a property that returns the form back and use it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but it seems this solution is close to CQRS pattern and a little advance to me, if there is a simpler way to do this it will be great. right now I am studying CQRS pattern